Get application insights to log messages at debug
I am having some fun with setting up application insights, I just can not get it to log debug messages.
I have the chunk of debug statements
_logger.LogTrace("Trace: I was here");
_logger.LogDebug("Debug: I was here");
_logger.LogInformation("Information: I was here");
_logger.LogWarning("Warning: I was here");
_logger.LogError("Error: I was here");
_logger.LogCritical("Critical: I was here");

And this is my set up in config
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "NotPostingMyConnectionStringOnStackOverflow" 
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug"
      }
    }
  },

But every time I run, it and look application insights it is only showing warning and above?
How do I get it to log at level debug?

My program.cs is set up like
 builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();


Please try the configuration which I have mentioned in this SOThread

Debug messages are logged as Verbose in Application Insights.

Have you tried the configuration which I have shared.

I have tried to log traces from .NET Core 8 Web App.
My Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    ConnectionString = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]
});


I am able to log all the severity levels even with the configuration you have shared.

The Debug logs are shown as Verbose in Transaction Search.



You can refer MSDoc, It explains setting _Critical_, _Error_, _Informational_, _LogAlways_, _Verbose_, or _Warning_ levels only.
Logs:


AFAIK,debug is a low level and allows you to log all the detailed information.Even Verbose does the same.

If you want to avoid all the unnecessary verbose messages, use the Configuration from this SOThread
which I have answered.

Even with my configuration, the debug logs are shown as Verbose.


